# Matplotlib: 3D line collection is plotted above any other drawing

Tags: python, matplotlib

I want to plot many lines (many times) so that I really need to use Line Collection for efficiency... however I noticed that the "zorder" is by default such that the lines are the last things to be drawn in the figure.
So, I didn't manage to plot a point above the line... Below you find a minimal example: I have tried to define the "zorder" but this seemed not to work...

```
import matplotlib.pyplot as plt
from mpl_toolkits.mplot3d.axes3d import Axes3D
from mpl_toolkits.mplot3d.art3d import Line3DCollection
import numpy as np

fig = plt.figure(figsize=(15,15))
ax  = fig.add_subplot(111, projection='3d',facecolor='w')
X = [(0,0,0,1,0),(0,0,1,0,0),(0,1,0,0,0)]
points = np.array([X[0], X[1], X[2]]).T.reshape(-1, 1, 3)
r = [(1.0, 1.0, 1.0, 1.0), (1.0, 0.75, 0.75, 1.0), (1.0, 0.5, 0.5, 1.0), (1.0, 0.25, 0.25, 1.0), (1.0, 0.0, 0.0, 1.0)];

segs = np.concatenate([points[:-1], points[1:]], axis = 1)
lc =Line3DCollection(segs,colors=list(r),linewidth=4)
ax.add_collection(lc)
ax.scatter(1,0,0,s=84)

plt.show()
```

Here is the result I'm getting:

[image: Result]

Any idea how to solve this?

Comment: This seems to work fine on Matplotlib==3.7.2